# org-mode with predictive mode key conflict

Tags: org-mode, keymap, predictive-mode

I'm using org-mode with predictive and having an issue with predictive changing a key binding that org-mode uses. Specifically, predictive changes M-tab and I prefer to keep org-mode's definition of M-tab.

I'm loading up predictive with

`(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'predictive-mode)`

which makes me think that I can do something like:
`(eval-after-load 'org-mode
    '(define-key....`

But I'm not sure if this is the correct "emacs" way to solve this problem.

Comment: SO has very good answers for this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102494/buffer-locally-overriding-minor-mode-key-bindings-in-emacs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, are you sure that the `M-tab` binding you like is from Org mode? The version of Org-mode I'm using (7.9.3f, from emacs 24.3) doesn't bind `M-tab`, if I'm reading things right. Check `C-h k M-TAB` to be sure.

If that's what you want, add it to a hook function (you don't want `eval-after-load`, because that will only be executed when the org-mode library loads, not whenever you start org-mode, which is what you want). Something like this *(warning: untested, because I haven't installed predictive)*:

```
(defun fixup-org-mode-keys ()
  (let* ((key     [(meta tab)])
         (binding (lookup-key org-mode-map key)))
    (require 'predictive)
    (predictive-mode 1)
    (local-set-key key binding)))
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'fixup-org-mode-keys)
```

If that's not the command you want, replace the `lookup-key` expression above with whatever function `C-h k M-TAB` reports, e.g.:

```
   ...(let* ((key     [(meta tab)])
             (binding 'pcomplete))
   ...
```

**An alternative method** is to disable predictive's `M-TAB` binding altogether. This is simpler, but has the effect of removing this binding *everywhere*. You may or may not like that, it's up to you:

```
(eval-after-load 'predictive (define-key predictive-map [(meta tab)] nil))
```

Comment: Closest I got is that the online docs for org indicate it is complete.  I at some point got it to point to `'pcomplete` while `M-<tab>` with predictive is `complete-or-cycle-word-at-point`.